# wxPython - Static Box Not Appearing

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython, linux-mint

I have inherited a problem that appears to have been put on the back burner by a colleague some time ago. In one of the applications written in Python 2.7 and wxPython 2.8 similar controls (e.g buttons) are grouped together and surrounded by a static box, which may or may not contain a heading (label) for the group. We are currently migrating from from Mint 13 TO Mint 17.3 but are having a problem that static boxes are just not appearing. Sizers are not in use. Has something been overlooked?

Comment: It should just work. Can you create a small, runnable example that demonstrates your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer, for those who find themselves in a similar predicament, is to be found in the Theme, being used for the Desktop.
In Control Centre is an Appearance setting and if you are using the Default Mint-X setting, click customise and if the controls setting is also Mint-X, it doesn't draw boxes for some reason.
Choose any other option in the controls list and the boxes magically appear. I hope this prevents someone else wasting hours looking for the solution.
See:[wxpython staticbox does not display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30095143/wxpython-staticbox-does-not-display)

Comment: I searched the questions using 'static box' and did not find your solution before posting. However if i use 'staticbox'  the answer appears!